# Systemd vs Upstart

Tags: upstart

When I attempt to boot using **systemd** the keyboard and mouse do not work.
When I boot using **upstart** the keyboard and mouse work fine.

### How do I get **systemd** working?

I have looked over the other answers, but nothing tell me how to tune 'systemd' so that it works.

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you using? And how are you switching between the two init systems?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 - when i boot the option is to boot with systemd or select other options, I choose the other then boot with upstart.